# IDL and XPA interaction

Tags: idl-programming-language

I'm having a problem getting programs launched by the IDL "spawn" command to be seen by XPA.  I'm trying to launch ds9 and then save a region file via IDL.  If I open a ds9 window from a terminal window, I can connect just fine with XPA in IDL.  However, if I launch ds9 through IDL, I get the error "XPA$ERROR no 'xpaget' access points match template: xpans".

What's the trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

XPA uses a name server program called 'xpans' to map the XPA target name ('ds9' in this case) to the host/socket pair used in the XPA communication. This name server can be started manually at the command line, but an XPA-enabled server such as DS9 will try to start xpans up automatically if one is not already running. In order to do this, DS9 must have xpans in its path. So the simplest explanation for your problem is that xpans is in your shell path which is passed to DS9 in the terminal window, but is not in your IDL path which is passed to DS9 from IDL. You can check this by starting up DS9 in each case, choosing File->XPA-Information, mousing out the XPA_METHOD value and running:

```
xpaget [xpa-method] -env PATH
```

This will contact DS9 directly (bypassing the name server) and will tell you the path DS9 has in each case. You also can do a 'ps' before and after DS9 is started in each case, and check for the xpans program ...

A second possible explanation is that IDL does indeed give DS9 the correct path, but is not allowing DS9 to start xpans, i.e. there could be an IDL restriction on whether an exec'ed process (DS9) can exec a sub-process (xpans). If that is the case, you will have to start xpans manually.